# Render PHP through Django

Tags: php, django, django-templates

Is there any way to render PHP files through Django for code Reusability. I have tried through django_php module and it was 10 year old module, so it does not support latest python versions (3.9)
Any help is appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run PHP from the command line, and capture the output; you can do this from
Python. You'll need to make sure you have the CLI version of PHP installed; on Ubuntu, you can do this with: `php7.3-cli` (substitute your version of `php`)

Here's an example of calling a PHP program from Python and printing the output:

```py
from subprocess import check_output

my_program_output = check_output(
    ["/path/to/php", "/path/to/my_program.php"]
).strip().decode("utf-8")

print(my_program_output)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I get this error while trying "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied". I have also tried Run as Administrator. Its still not working.

Comment: Ah, you're running on Windows. If you open up the command prompt and type `php --version`, what output do you get? You might need to be explicit, and include `php.exe` in your path to the file. Then, for example, change the line to be something like: `["C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.14", "C:/my_path/my_program.php"]`

Comment: When I type  php --version in cmd, I get this  

`PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2020 22:02:58) ( NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies`

And When I give the php.exe path as you said, I get different error now -
`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/xampp/php/php.exe', 'C:/users/rakesh/Desktop/testprint.php']' returned non-zero exit status 4294967295.`

I have also tried mentioning php-cgi.exe, I get the same error.

NOTE: I have php installed folder in two or three locations. Is that a problem?

Comment: Two things. From `cmd`, what happens when you type `where php`? That'll let you know which one it is calling. Second, try wrapping your subprocess call in a try / except block to see if we can get more details.
try:
    subprocess.check_output(...)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)